# How can I modify jQuery to allow $('dialog').showModal() to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to show a modal dialog using a jQuery script. Using the $ approach to get the element and call the function results in an error, but using vanilla JS to get the element and call the function works as expected. How can I make the call work using the $ approach to get the element?

**Vanilla JavaScript**

Works as expected. No errors on Chrome v67.0.3396.87.

```js
document.getElementById("error").showModal()
```

```html
<dialog id="error">Error message</dialog>
```

**jQuery (v3.3.1)**

Does not work as expected. Returns an error on the same browser.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).showModal is not a function

```js
$('#error').showModal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dialog id="error">Error message</dialog>
```

I realize what's probably happening is [dialog.showModal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) functionality is still experimental, so jQuery may not have formal support for it yet. However, I expected that any functions or properties not overridden by jQuery would cascade to the vanilla JavaScript functions and properties. That is evidently not the case, so I could use some help to make $('#dialog').showModal() behave functionally like document.getElementById("dialog").showModal().

Edit: I'm trying to use this like any other typical jQuery call within my scripts. For more context, here's how I'm trying to use the calls.

```js
err = $('#error');

err.html('New error message'); //err = $('#error')[0] results in an error here
err.showModal(); //err = $('#error') results in an error here

//err.show() does not create the supporting elements that showModal() does
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dialog id="error">error</dialog>
```

Comment: try this $('#error')[0].showModal(); Jquery wraps the DOM element

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it's counter-intuitive to require the 0-index reference for a single element query. Is there any way I can modify the behavior to automatically make the association implicitly, like for any other '#' query?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery JQuery always returns an array. :-(

Comment: Good reading. Explains why the 0-index specifier works. What I need to find out next is why calls like html() work without requiring the 0-index specifier, and then do the same for showModal().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modifying the showModal() call meets my requirements:

```js
$.fn.showModal = function() {
    el = $(this);
    if (el.is('dialog')) {
        el[0].showModal();
    }
    return el;
};

err = $('#error');
err.html('New error message');
err.showModal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dialog id="error">error</dialog>
```

At some point I'll need to add in browser compatibility checks to cascade to some degraded mode alternative. Also need to add a jQuery version number check in case formal support for the call is added in a future version.

Answer (score 2):

Extend jQuery

```
jQuery.fn.extend({showModal: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
           if(this.tagName=== "DIALOG"){
                this.showModal();
            }
        });
 }});
```

Use as

`$('#error').showModal()`;

Comment: .show() only shows the dialog element itself. It does not create the supporting elements like the gray div underneath to block other user actions on the page.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Looks like we both resorted to extending the function. I had to learn how to do that. Useful for these types of situations. Never had to think about it before since jQuery's always "just worked" in the past :)